# MongoDB sort array<String> got wrong result

Tags: mongodb

My documents is as below:

```
{
   customs: ['111', '222'] 
}
{
   customs: ['222', '333'] 
}
{
   customs: ['111', '222', '333'] 
}
```

When I sort with `db.find('user').sort({customs: 1})`, I get the correct result:

```
{
   customs: ['111', '222'] 
}
{
   customs: ['111', '222', '333'] 
}
{
   customs: ['222', '333'] 
}
```

However, when I sort with `db.find('user').sort({customs: -1})`, I get an incorrect result:

```
{
   customs: ['111', '222', '333'] 
}
{
   customs: ['222', '333'] 
}
{
   customs: ['111', '222'] 
}
```

Does someone have any idea?

Comment: what do you need exactly to sort, the outer document or the inner array customs?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you define "correct".

The example sort shown exactly matches the description in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#arrays) of how arrays are sorted:

> With arrays, a less-than comparison or an ascending sort compares the smallest element of arrays, and a greater-than comparison or a descending sort compares the largest element of the arrays. As such, when comparing a field whose value is a single-element array (e.g. [ 1 ]) with non-array fields (e.g. 2), the comparison is between 1 and 2. A comparison of an empty array (e.g. [ ]) treats the empty array as less than null or a missing field.

Comment: If i want to sort array to be the result: {
   customs: ['222', '333'] 
}
{
   customs: ['111','222', '333'] 
}
{
   customs: ['111', '222']}, how to do